# Does Silverlight 3.0 contain session mechanics?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to find out if Silverlight 3.0 has any session mechanics - as far as I recall, SL2 was suffering from the lack of it. If SL 3.0 doesn't have it (Sadly) - are there any good reads regarding session mechanics implementation?

I'm considering using a client-side singleton object to hold the session instance + a WCF service + a SQL Server DB - is this a good way to go?

Comment: Can you confirm what you mean by session mechanics? being able to share objects between different instances of the app? if you mean like asp.net then im confused as silverlight instances are obviously stateful between actions unlike traditional http.

Comment: what I mean is maintaining some sort of a session state, logged in/out / permissions etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Silverlight is a client-only technology and doesn't necessarily have the same "session" or cookie semantics that ASP.NET has as a result.

You're more than free to

- pass information to and from web services and your back-end,
- store information on the machine in isolated storage (similar to a session, but do be careful - data is not encrypted unless you encrypt it),
- use the HTML interoperability features to get/set/call JavaScript and the serving web page's DOM
- allow your server to provide authentication and authorization, to enable login, out, etc.

Comment: how do I go about the last option?

Comment: The last option means "leave it to the web server", so use a standard login, logout, etc., URL. Your client app doesn't need to be involved.